# HOW to understand custom drawn ? Which tools can I use?

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface, custom-draw

I want to know the tools that beautiful UI programs using?

Comment: This is a very generalized question. I would recommend asking a more specific one for stackoverflow.

Comment: The best tools are often your left and right hands, combined with your eyes and brain.  Then you take about 10-15 years of working them every day for hours each day to learn how to UI program.  You spend countless hours learning what works and what does not. Spend days with customers finding out what they do and do not like.  Get critiqued to hell and keep pushing.  Then after some time...you might actually be able to create a worth while ui.

Comment: thanks! you are right, I will try my best to understand and design UI.

Comment: We don't have any way to know what you intend by "understand custom drawn", or "beautiful UI programs". Be specific. Describe exactly what are you trying to do, and give an example of something you have seen (with a link) which is doing it. Someone then may be able to suggest appropriate libraries and/or tools.

Comment: Visual Studio,QT and Glade+ are very good solutions.

Comment: Thank you! Now I use the Windows native API and MFC to build the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to ask a better question.  What platform are you targeting?  What framework are you using?  "Beautiful" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: thanks! The platform is win32 xp. I use the VS2008. Can I use MFC?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to.  Give it a try!  The best way to learn something new is to jump in and see what you bang your head on.

Comment: Thank you! I am confused when I see so many UI. I don't know how and where to start? But I will have a try using MFC!

Comment: Are you going to be targeting only Windows environments or do you need your application to be cross-platform?  There are many considerations you should look at when choosing your framework.